# Programatic way of counting floating point operations (JAVA)

Tags: java, runtime, time-complexity, flops

I'm looking for a programmatic way of counting the number of floating point operations (flops) in call to a function, in JAVA.

There are several closely related questions, asking about what floating points are, and how to do big-O computational complexity analysis, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795333/whats-a-floating-point-operation-and-how-to-count-them-in-matlab), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670784/counting-flops-need-some-explanation-matlab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm). But note that in my application I don't want a big-O number, I want to know for a particular run of a function (i.e. a particular input data size) how many flops did it take.

The two closest solutions I can find are [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812446/a-method-of-counting-floating-point-operations-in-a-c-cuda-program-using-ptx) suggestions to use a run-time profiler to count the number of flops, but this does not suit my needs as I need to use the result later in the program and [(2)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Utilitiesforflopfloatingpointoperationcounting.htm) a library of computation functions which can be called to increment a counter, and a closely related suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725289/automatic-way-to-obtain-the-floating-point-operation-count-for-some-piece-of-cod).

These last two suggestions would meet my needs but involve a lot of manual modifications to the code I need to count. An alternative would be to just use CPU run-time which would be very quick and easy, but also quite rough.

Is anyone aware of a programmatic way of counting the flops executed by a section of code?